# Jquery multiple selectors, select items which match both criteria

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

if i do this...

```
$('.class1, .class2').hide();
```

Then all items with class1 or with class2 will be hidden.

```
<pre class='class1'>hello1</pre>
<pre class='class2'>hello2</pre>
<pre class='class1 class2'>hello3</pre>
```

What is the syntax so only the 3rd `<pre>` will be hidden, I want to hide things based if they have both class1 and class2.

Comment: Note that JQuery selectors are really mimicing CSS selectors, so this problem could just as easily have been a CSS problem! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The same as the CSS selectors for it -  class identifiers with no spaces in between:

```
$('.class1.class2').hide();
```

jQuery documentation here:  [.class.class  selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/class#classclass).

Although if these classes are only going to be on `<pre>` elements, this is best:

```
$('pre.class1.class2').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply, thats exactly what i needed. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that syntax works to combine other sorts of jquery things, e.g. $(':input:visible') finds visible input tags.