# Jquery multiple selector criteria with Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm trying to select items which match `".class#id"`, something that seems so natural as per [Jquery multiple selectors, select items which match both criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079646/jquery-multiple-selectors-select-items-which-match-both-criteria) ,

but it only seems to work in firefox.  Does IE just not support this?!

Specifically, I have

```
<div id="A" class="x">
  <div id="A" class="y">
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to select `$( ".y#A" )`

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Can you provide some sample markup and jQuery?  Or are you using the exact example in the question you have linked to?

Comment: Works for me in IE. Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kGa8G/1/

Comment: Don't you want `$(".class, #id")`, as the way you have it will look for items with the id of `id` within other items with the class `class`

Comment: You really shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID, so I wouldn't be surprised if quirks come up.

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.  All browsers handle this differently, so there is no way to be sure how it's handled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not have multiple elements with the same identifier. Internet Explorer probably recognizes this. (Or does not recognize this, but it coincidentally has a bug that behaves as if it did, and Microsoft decided to call it a feature.)

Simply give the elements that currently have the same ids, different ids and a common class name. Then you can use`$('.class.class2')` and it will work in IE.

Answer (score 2):

IE will complain that you have 2 elements with the same ID and cause some unusual behaviour.